# How to append an array to an existing `.npz` file?

Tags: python, numpy, save

I have the following code, which generate the mat file (in `.npz` format):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
np.savez('mat',x)
```

Now I want to append another array to the existing file:

```
y = np.arange(21)
np.savez('mat',y)
```

But, it replaces the x array with y. 
I want to have both of these arrays in the file. Besides, I do not want to write them to the file at the same time.

Comment: afaik you cannot do that its an all or nothing type operation ... you could save it to a string and append the string to the file ... but it would not decode properly

Comment: An `npz` is a `zip` archive.  So you might be able `np.save('y.npy', y)`, and add that file to `npz` with an OS archive tool.

Answer (score 3):

I took the comments on the post as a start and the following code seems to do what you want. (I'm using python 3.6 and base modules only, it probably works for other python versions)

```
import zipfile
import io
import os
import numpy as np

test_np1 = np.random.random(100)
test_np2 = np.random.random(100)

# initial file
filename = 'npfile.npz'
try:
    np.savez_compressed(filename, test_np1=test_np1)

    with np.load(filename) as loaded_npz:
        print(np.array_equal(test_np1, loaded_npz['test_np1']))

    bio = io.BytesIO()
    np.save(bio, test_np2)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'a') as zipf:
        # careful, the file below must be .npy
        zipf.writestr('test_np2.npy', data=bio.getbuffer().tobytes())

    with np.load(filename) as loaded_npz:
        print(np.array_equal(test_np1, loaded_npz['test_np1']))
        print(np.array_equal(test_np2, loaded_npz['test_np2']))
finally:
    os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step1:** create your first file

```
d = np.arange(10)
np.savez("mat",x = d)  # do not forget to name your variable d
```

**Step2:** read your file, convert it to a dictionary object, add your new variable to the dictionary, and finally overwrite your `mat.npz` with this dictionary

```
data = np.load("mat.npz")
data = dict(data)
data["y"] = np.arange(21)
np.savez("mat",**data)
```

**Step 3:** to verify if the last variable is added to the `mat.npz` file.

```
data = np.load("mat.npz")
print(data[x])   # [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
print(data[y])   # [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution here but I'd like to share a way to add array to a new nyz file.

```
import numpy as np

array_dict = {'new_array': new_array}
for k in old_npz_file:
    array_dict[k] = old_npz_file[k]

np.savez(file_path, **array_dict)
```

I think you could say it's one way to "add" array.

Comment: What do you mean by "not a real solution"? Where does `old_npz_file` come from? Could you maybe edit the code so that it's self explanatory or add explanation?

Comment: the `old_npz_file` is just the npz file to which you want to add a new npy file, here I just thought since `numpy.savez` takes key word argumets as the name of npy files in the npz file, using a dict to store them would be neat. As you can see I have to copy old npy files to the dict, I think that's not what @Cicilio wants.